# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Uri

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, android-activity

I am receiving the following error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Uri" from the following line

```
list_item_bac = i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac");
```

list_item_bac have been identified has a Uri since it populates an image through JSON data so I do not want to change it from Uri to String since I am not returning text but an image that I would cast to an imageview.

Below is the entire code:

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    Uri list_item_bac;

    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);


        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this),
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");
        list_item_bac = i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac");



        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

        // Get image URLs from your previous network request...
        // I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
        Uri url1 = list_item_bac;   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        Uri url2 = list_item_bac;
        Uri url3 = list_item_bac;

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Update

```
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1247
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:130)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.<init>(ImageRequest.java:71)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:220)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:171)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary(NetworkImageView.java:140)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.onLayout(NetworkImageView.java:180)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onLayout(HorizontalScrollView.java:1474)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-29 13:15:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are retrieving a String and trying to set it to a URI. You have to parse it. Try this:

```
list_item_bac = Uri.parse(i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac"));
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. It makes more sense now. When applying this change, I have received the following error in the activity in eclipse: "The method setImageUrl(String, ImageLoader) in the type NetworkImageView is not applicable for the arguments (Uri, ImageLoader)" at the line  hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
if you could kindly provide another suggestion, that would be greatly helpful.

Comment: In this case, you DO want a string, not a URI. Since the method setInageUrl takes in a string, you will want to convert the URI to a string before you pass it in

Comment: Thanks for your response. In doing so, I have encountered a nullpointer exception error. I have kindly added the log cat message under the update section of my initial post.